# Многопоточность в С++: создать поток для конкретного объекта с передачей в конструктор имени нестатической функции

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Здравствуйте, недавно пришлось заняться разработкой многопоточного приложения (впервые) и наткнулся на такую проблему: позарез нужно создать поток для конкретного объекта с передачей в конструктор имени нестатической функции, гугл ничего путного не дал.

1. Подскажите, это вообще возможно?
2. Если нет, то как это 'лечиться'?

В абстракции: есть класс `System`, у него есть нестатический метод `private update()` который я должен отслеживать, путем инициализации указателя `private thread* Thread` в конструкторе класса.

P.S в `update` вызывается метод `move(...)`, который привязан к объекту, т.е я не могу сделать `update` статическим без создания контейнера, хранящего все данные о пользователях, а это затратно

```
#include <thread>
//еще включения ...
class System
{
    //некоторые поля и методы...
    //...
    thread* Thread;
    static thread* sThread;

    System() {
       Thread = new thread(update);//ошибка! отсутствуют экземпляры констуктора соответствующий ... для std::thread::thread (void())
    }
    void update() {
        //...
        move(...);
        //...
    }
    void move() {
    //работает с полями объекта
    }
};

{
//где-то создается System* system = System;
}
```

P.S(2) Перелез с c#, там можно инициализировать потоки нестатическими методами(вроде), не судите строго

Comment: А лямбды не помогают?

Comment: @Qwertiy, эм, каким тут боком могут зайти лямба выражения? Не могу ж я этот метод лямбой заменить, конструктор thread принимает ссылку на адрес ф-ции, да и нужно мне именно так, как я написал(, переписываю программу с С#

Comment: Насколько я понял, вы хотите создать поток, функция которого зависит от состояния объекта? Т.е. дать потоку на выполнение функцию-член класса?

Comment: @Shadasviar именно!

Comment: @Xambey, а создание потока осуществляется внутри функции-члена класса или вне его?

Comment: @Shadasviar внутри конструктора, при создании объекта, дополнил текст

Comment: thread достаточно умный, чтобы понимать, что от него хотят - см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации](//ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) говорится, что конструктор выглядит так:

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

поэтому могу предположить, что следует использовать лямбда-функцию как-то так:

```
new thread([&]() { this.update(); })
```

В любом случае следует быть осторожным со временем жизни объектов.

Answer (score 4):

Также возможен вариант с использованием `std::bind`

```
System() {
   Thread = new std::thread(std::bind(&System::update, this));
}
```

Comment: `new std::thread(std::bind, System::update, this);`?)))

Comment: Спасибо вам, жаль нельзя выбрать несколько вариантов ответа

Comment: @Qwertiy нет, это будет вызов bind вместо вызова update

Answer (score 2):

Я абсолютно не уверен в том, что это хорошая идея, но используя лямбду вместо `update` и дополнительно дав компилятору опцию `-pthread` мне удалось запустить, и даже получить результат следующего кода:

```
class System
{
//некоторые поля и методы...
//...

    static thread* sThread;
public:
  thread* Thread;
    System() {
       Thread = new thread([this]{
        /*Это код метода update, который вызывает move, лямбда
        должна захватить указатель на текущий объект чтоб вызвать функцию объекта */
        cout << "Updte\n";
        this->move();
      });
    }
private:
    void move() {
      cout << "Move\n";
    }
};

int main(){
  System s;
  s.Thread->join();
  return 0;
}
```

Повторю, что по-моему это все имеет кучу подводных камней, поэтому интересно увидеть ответы более знающих людей.

Answer (score 2):

А зачем сложно, если можно просто? Указать, что это функция-член, и добавить `this`?

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    Test(int x):x(x){};
    void out(int b) { cout << x << ":" << b << endl; }
    void run(int j)
    {
        thread t = thread(&Test::out,this,j);
        t.join();
    }
private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    Test t(12);
    t.run(3);
}
```